# Why does basic OpenGL application crash only under Windows?

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, glew

I have successfully setup env on Linux (which is my daily driver) and tried to move the same codebase to windows. Well, as it might be obvious - it did not work out. It compiles just fine and once I try to run it, I get this error code:

```
Process finished with exit code -1073741515 (0xC0000135)
```

I have attempted to debug the code, but the debugger `return 1` on me every time I try to run it.

Okay, here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    GLFWwindow* window;

    if (!glfwInit())
    {
        std::cout << "Init of glfw failed!" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Hello World", nullptr, nullptr);
    if (!window)
    {
        std::cout << "Window failed to be created!" << std::endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK)
    {
        std::cout << "ERROR" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    std::cout << "Version: " << glGetString(GL_VERSION) << std::endl;

    float position[6] =
              {
                  -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f
              };

    unsigned buffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &buffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 6 * sizeof(float), position, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 2, nullptr);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwTerminate();

    return 0;
}
```

The issue is, that once I comment out everything from

```
    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK)
    {
        std::cout << "ERROR" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
```

It opens the window, and then quickly closes without the crash.

Comment: Maybe a basic question, but have  you updated your windows OpenGL driver/toolchain?

Comment: Very good question. No. I shall do that right now.

Comment: @Amadeus I am using latest GLEW 2.1.0, with GLFW straight from https://github.com/glfw/glfw repository. Glew is altered a little and build with `-nostdlib`, but still build on my machine. Linking the glew instance (build for mingw-gcc) does not change the result. CMake find OpenGL libs: opengl32;glu32 and I even went ahead to quickly compile `freeglut.dll.a` just to be sure, and link it. No change. Still crashing badly. I cannot check the version of GL, because there is no init unfortunately.

Comment: It is difficult to say anything without looking how everything is installed. So, my suggestion is to use something that is already functioning, like, for example, https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Creating-a-window and https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Hello-Window or try to put, before `glewInit()` -> `glewExperimental = GL_TRUE`(http://glew.sourceforge.net/basic.html)

Comment: `0xC0000135` is `STATUS_DLL_NOT_FOUND`, check how you link when compiling the code and what libraries the exe imports, then make sure these libraries exist in your system and are up-to-date.

Comment: This is certainly possible. I might have ommited `TARGET_LINK_DIRECTORIES`. I am unable to check it out rn, I shall do it asap and update in comment. Thank you for teaching me something new (about `STATUS_DLL_NOT_FOUND`)!

Comment: Okay, After I have download compiled DLL and linking it I have succeeded in starting the app. Question is, why after compiling glew on this machine, with the same mingw64-gcc I got information, that my glew.dll is not meant for this system. I am really confused, but I have succeeded. Thank you for such a great amount of help and information filled comments!